# How to change the resolution of PS5 camera in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am trying to change the resolution of PS5 camera in OpenCV, Python.

The problem is that PS5 Camera officially isn't supported on PC, and I have to use custom camera drivers from GitHub: https://github.com/Hackinside/PS5_camera_files

Default image resolution by this code is 640x376

```
self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
```

I found out that supported resolutions of this camera are 640x376 and 5148×1088, so I tried to do next:

```
res = self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 5148)
res = self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1088)
```

But in both cases `res` is `False`, and resolution doesn't change. I can recieve only small resolution frame.

Camera 100% can work in 5148×1088, because if I launch Windows Camera application it shows me high quality images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was, that I had a piece of code, where I read a frame from the capture using a loop:

```
while True:
    self.capture.read()
```

It was in a parallel thread so changing the resolution was at the same time as reading images. It was a reason why the change resolution process always failed.

So the provided code in question should work if you do it before starting reading images.